# replacing variables in syntax object

Tags: racket

I'd like to replace all occurrences of `v1` in a syntax object like `#'(or (and v1 v2) (and v1 v3))` to `v4` to get `#'(or (and v4 v2) (and v4 v3))`. What would be the easiest way to do so in Racket? Should I convert the syntax to list or string to replace and convert it back to syntax?

Answer (score 2):

Use `with-syntax`.

```
(with-syntax ([v1 #'v4])
  #'(or (and v1 v2) (and v1 v3)))
```

The output:

```
#<syntax:3:4 (or (and v4 v2) (and v4 v3))>
```

Turning this into a macro looks like:

```
#lang racket
(require (for-syntax syntax/parse))

(define-syntax (replace-id stx)
  (syntax-parse stx
    [(_replace-id from to so)
     (syntax/loc stx
       (with-syntax ([from #'to])
         #'so))]))

(replace-id v1 v4 #'(or (and v1 v2) (and v1 v3)))
```

If you want to use `replace-id` in a macro, then wrap `begin-syntax` around
the definition in order to define it in phase 1.

Comment: Thanks. What if I want to wrap this into a function? `(define (foo stx) (with-syntax ([v1 #'v4]) stx))` doesn't seem to work?

Comment: Added a macro instead.

Comment: Can you explain what `(with-syntax ([from #'to]) #'so)` does in `replace-id`? I get it that `(_replace-id from to so)` matches `so` to be `#'(or (and v1 v2) (and v1 v3))`, but how does `with-syntax` perform the replacement? I read the doc for `with-syntax` but didn't get it :(

Comment: The `#'so` is short for `(syntax so)`. As it turns out you need to read the section on `syntax` (which is just after the section on `with-syntax`). The form `(syntax template)` constructs a syntax object based on a template, which can include pattern variables bound by syntax-case or with-syntax. Since we used `with-syntax` to bind `from` we will in effect replace instances of the identifier `from`. See more here: http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/stx-patterns.html#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fstxcase-scheme..rkt%29._syntax%29%29

Comment: Thanks. My understanding is that `with-syntax` tries to match `#'so` to `from`, and if it matches then replace it with `#'to` instead. But in this case `#'so` is `#'(or (and v1 v2) (and v1 v3))` so wouldn't that just replace the entire syntax object with `#'to`?

Comment: First `(with-syntax ([from #'to]) body)` binds `from` to a syntax object. If `from` appears in a syntax template within body, then the identifier `from` will be replaced with the value it is bound to  (here #'to)). That is: `with-syntax` does not matching, it simply binds identifiers that can be referred to in a syntax template.

Comment: I see. So why wouldn't something like `(define-syntax (replace-id from to stx) (with-syntax ([from #'to]) stx))` work?

Comment: Because the body of `define-syntax` needs to return a syntax transformer. You could use `define-syntax-rule` instead. If I recall correctly: `(define-syntax-rule (replace-id from to stx) (with-syntax ([from #'to]) stx))`.

Comment: and why does using a function not work either? `(define (replace-id from to stx) (with-syntax ([from #'to]) stx))`

Comment: It is `#'` aka `syntax` that replaces identifiers in the template. A lone `with-syntax` does nothing to `stx`.

Comment: I guess my question is why does `(with-syntax ([v1 #'v4]) #'(or (and v1 v2) (and v1 v3)))` by itself works, but once I abstract this into a function as `(define (replace-id from to stx) (with-syntax ([from #'to]) stx))` and call it as `(replace-id #'v1 #'v4 #'(or (and v1 v2) (and v1 v3)))` then it doesn't work. Sorry if this is a stupid question!

Comment: In ` (with-syntax ([from #'to]) stx))` there is no `syntax` around `stx`. However: ` (with-syntax ([from #'to]) (syntax stx)))` doesn't work as-is, since the template you want is not `stx` but the `(or ...)`. This means we need `(syntax (or ...))` as the template. Now *if* `syntax` were a function, we could write `(syntax stx)` but alas `syntax` is a macro. In order to produce `(syntax (or ...))` we therefore need a macro. That's why I wrote a macro in the answer.

Answer (score 2):

There are several different strategies you can use depending on what the final syntax object is used for. In particular, it depends on whether you can expand the syntax to get a different syntax object with the same behavior, or whether you have to leave everything exactly as it was.

#### 1. If the final syntax object is used as an expression in the output of a macro

If the final syntax object is only used as an expression in the output of a macro, then *expanding* the syntax object is fine, since the run-time behavior is what matters, not the exact form of the syntax. In this case, you can expand the syntax object in an *internal-definition-context* that includes the substitution.

```
;; create a context where x-old is renamed to x-new
(define ctx (syntax-local-make-definition-context))
(syntax-local-bind-syntaxes 
  (list x-old) 
  #`(make-rename-transformer (quote-syntax #,x-new))
  ctx)

;; expand the syntax in that context
(local-expand stx 'expression '() ctx)
```

#### 2. If the final syntax object is supposed to be kept exactly as is, and cannot be expanded

If the final syntax object is supposed to be kept exactly as is, except for the substitution, then you can't expand it. You have to traverse it somehow to do the substitution. This comes with several problems if the code you're substituting into might use certain features like `quote` or `syntax->datum`. However, there are times when its necessary, and for those times I use a `traverse-stx/recur` function with this signature:

```
;; traverse-stx/recur : Stx [Stx -> Stx] -> Stx
;; Traverses `stx`, calling the `recur` function on every sub-piece
(define (traverse-stx/recur stx recur)
  ....)
```

Which I use like this:

```
;; stx-subst : Stx Id Id -> Stx
;; Replaces every instance of `x-old` with `x-new` in the syntax `stx`
(define (stx-subst stx x-old x-new)
  ;; traverse : Stx -> Stx
  (define (traverse s)
    (cond [(and (identifier? stx) (free-identifier=? stx x-old))
           x-new]
          [else
           ;; pass "yourself" as the recur callback, so that it calls
           ;; you on every sub-piece
           (traverse-stx/recur stx traverse)]))
  (traverse s))
```

The definition of `traverse-stx/recur` might depend on the language you're traversing, but if it's literally just arbitrary s-expressions with no "meaning" that you're afraid of changing, then it can be structured just like a normal s-expression traversal, though with `stx-null?`, `stx-car`, `stx-cdr`, etc. (from the `syntax/stx` library) instead of the normal `null?`, `car`, `cdr`, etc.

NOTE: however you define the traversal for your language, a helper function like this might be useful:

```
;; restore : Stx Any -> Stx
;;           Any Any -> Any
(define (restore orig datum)
  (if (syntax? orig) (datum->syntax orig datum orig orig) datum))
```

#### 3. When you need to rely on and preserve the "meaning" in a different core language

In some rare cases, might want to expand to a different "core language" than Racket's core forms. This is still an active area of research and hasn't been totally figured out yet. However, current strategies involve traversing the syntax object manually like (2), while also expanding the syntax using an *internal-definition-context* like (1), and reconstructing the syntax after the expansion.

The best explanation I've seen so far for how to do this is in this [Blog Post by Alexis King](https://lexi-lambda.github.io/blog/2018/04/15/reimplementing-hackett-s-type-language-expanding-to-custom-core-forms-in-racket/). But this is very hard to do correctly, and the more complicated your "core language" is, the harder it becomes.

Comment: Thanks. But how can I create a syntax object back in the `else` case, which requires concatenating `(stx-car stx)` and `(traverse-stx/recur stx traverse)`?

Comment: I've updated my answer to include a `restore` helper function. Whenever `traverse-stx/recur` function destructures a form, like a `stx-pair?` for example, it should re-construct it using something like `(restore stx (cons (recur (stx-car stx)) (recur (stx-cdr stx))))`.

Comment: For your solution #2, that is a situation where you might genuinely want `bound-identifier=?` instead of `free-identifier=?`, depending on the details.

Comment: For my uses of solution #2, it's usually been the case that the definition comes from outside the syntax object I'm substituting in. And because of that outside definition, `free-identifier=?` seemed right. My understanding is that `bound-identifier=?` is what you should use when the would-be definition(s) and reference(s) are all inside, and that definitions from outside should be ignored.